# generics, method signatures, assignments

Tags: java, generics

I thought I understood this but obviously not...

I have a method signature like so:

`void doSomething(List<TypeA> typeAs){...}`

`List<TypeA<TypeB>> getTypeBTypeAs(){...}`

but if I try and call

`doSomething(getTypeBTypeAs());`

I get a compile error: "the method doSomething(List) in the type ... is not applicable for the arguments (List>)"

however if i change the sig of `doSomething` to

`void doSomething(List<TypeA<?>> typeAs){...}`

it still doesn't work, but

`void doSomething(List typeAs){...}`

obviously it works as i bypass generics.

which seems odd.

Can someone fill me in?

Also, in this case I'd like `doSomething` to work with any List containing TypeAs of any generic type; undefined, TypeB, TypeC etc.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic class `TypeA<TypeB>` is a different type from `TypeA`. You can't pass in a parameter of type `TypeA<TypeB>` where the method expects a `TypeA`. Also `TypeA<TypeB>` is a different type from `TypeA<TypeC>`, so the same constraints apply.

The classic example (from [Effective Java, 2nd Ed.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) AFAIR) is: we have containers for animals (`Container<Animal>`) and as subclasses of `Animal` we have `Lion` and `Butterfly`. Now, if you have a method

```
void func(Animal animal);
```

it will accept both lions and butterflies. However, this function

```
void func(Container<Animal> animalContainer);
```

will not accept a `Container<Lion>`, neither a `Container<Butterfly>`. Do realize that a strong cage useful for keeping lions safely would not stop butterflies from flying away, and vice versa a thick but light net to hold butterflies would not stand a chance against a lion.

If you really are sure that any kind of animal container suits you, declare your function like this:

```
void func(Container<? extends Animal> animalContainer);
```

Back to your case, I guess the only method to accept both `List<TypeA>` and `List<TypeA<TypeB>>` would be something like this:

```
void doSomething(List<?> list);
```

Comment: If Effective Java has a generics example, it must be in the second edition, because I have the first edition sitting on my desk, and it's several years older than Java 5.

Comment: yes, it's in the second edition. And it's available online, google it (Effective Java Generics)

Comment: Also, if you did want the second func to accept a Container containing any animal, it would be `void func(Container<? extends Animal> animalContainer);` would it not?

Comment: then how do i set up a method ie `doSomething` to accept a list containing any incarnation of `List<TypeA>` ?

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, I added a link to the book. @R. Bemrose As chance would have it, I added the same solution at the same time :-)

Comment: @pstanton Could you specify more exactly what you mean by "any incarnation of `List<TypeA>`" ?

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHA! so `List<TypeA<TypeB>>` will match `List<? extends TypeA>` .. that's what i didn't understand. I thought that was designed for where `class TypeB extends TypeA` you could assign a `List<TypeB>` to `List<? extends TypeA>`. that's a little misleading, but i guess it works!. thx.

Comment: @pstanton I added an answer to your previous question. I am afraid that since `TypeA<TypeB>>` is not a `TypeA` (unless `TypeA` is a standard library container), this won't work.

Comment: no, that doesn't work, but you've already answered my question... `List<? extends TypeA>` does match `List<TypeA>` as well as `List<TypeA<TypeB>>`, which is all i need. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<T> void doSomething(List<TypeA<T>> typeAs) { ... }
```

Note the `<T>` at the beginning of the line. That way doSomething accepts every List containing any TypeAs.

Comment: you're right, now i understand what you meant with "undefined".