# How to correctly refactor this?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

I have trouble finding way to correctly refactor this code so that there would be as little duplicate code as possible, I have a couple of methods like this (pseudocode):

```
public List<Something> parseSomething(Node n){
  List<Something> somethings = new ArrayList<Something>();
  initialize();
  sameCodeInBothClasses();
  List<Node> nodes = getChildrenByName(n, "somename");
  for(Node n:nodes){
    method();
    actionA();
    somethings.add(new Something(actionB());
  }
  return somethings;
}
```

methods `sameCodeInBothClasses()` are same in all classes but where it differs is what hapens in for loop `actionA()` and it also adds an element to the List of different type.

Should I use Strategy pattern for the different parts inside loop?

What about the return value (The type of list differs), should the method return just `List<Object>` that I would then cast to appropriate type? Should I pass the class I want to return as parameter?

Comment: do the methods `sameCodeInBothClasses()`, `method()`, `actionA()` cause any side effects? in other words, does this parse method do more than just parsing something from the given node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applicable design pattern is [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), rather than Strategy.

About the different type of items, I would try genericizing `parseSomething` first, like this:

```
public <T> List<T> parseSomething(Node n){
  List<T> somethings = new ArrayList<T>();
  initialize();
  sameCodeInBothClasses();
  List<Node> nodes = getChildrenByName(n, "somename");
  for(Node n:nodes){
    method();
    actionA();
    somethings.add(new T(actionB());
  }
  return somethings;
}
```

This may not work for you straight away though. You may need to move the generic parameter to the class level.

Returning `List<Object>` will not work, as generic collections are *invariant*: for
any two distinct types `Type1` and `Type2`, `List<Type1>` is neither a subtype nor a
supertype of `List<Type2>` (even if `Type1` and `Type2` are related, i.e. one is a subtype of the other!). See [an earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292308/generics-method-signatures-assignments/2292339#2292339) for more details on this.

So if all else fails, the quick and dirty solution would be indeed to use a non generic `List`.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely, plus I used also the strategy pattern so the only thing that happens inside the for loop is genericParser.doTheStuff(), where a concrete parser (implementation of GenericParser interface) is passed at runtime.. I'm quite happy with this solution as there is no more duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

If you write it like this:

```
public List<T> parseGeneric(Node n) {
  List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
  initialize();
  sameCodeInBothClasses();
  List<Node> nodes = getChildrenByName(n, "somename");
  for(Node n:nodes){
    method();
    actionA();
    result.add(new T(actionB()));
  }
  return result;
}
```

And invoke it as

```
List<Something> somethings = parseGeneric(aSomething);
```

It's hard to say with all these other methods sprinkled around without a definition available, but I believe you should be able to get away with something like the above.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to declare `parseSomething` in an abstract base class, with the methods that are different for each class declared as `abstract` and implemented in the subclasses.  The inline code that creates a `Something` instance would need to be turned into a factory method.

The problem is that the signature of `parseSomething` needs to return notionally different types; e.g. `List<Something>` versus `List<SomethingElse>`.  One approach would be to identify a common supertype and make the return type `List<? extends SomeSuper>`.  Another approach would be to create `parseXxx` methods with the required signatures in each leaf class and have them delegate to a `protected List<? extends SomeSuper> doParse(...)` method in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an Action interface for methods actionA and actionB.  Then a Parser class with a method parseSomething:

```
public List parseSomething(Node n, Action a) {
  List something = new ArrayList();
  initialize();
  samecode();
  List<Node> nodes = getChildrenByName(n, "name");
  for(Node n: nodes) {
      a.actionA();
      somethings.add(new Something(a.actionB()));
  }
  return somethings;
}
```