# Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> myMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Boolean>>();

Tags: java, dictionary, nested, hashmap

Why doesn't that work in java, but this does

```
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> myMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,Boolean>>();
```

Just to clarify the below alteration of the nested HashMap shows a compiler error, whereas the above does not not; with a Map (not hashmap)

```
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> myMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Boolean>>();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because generics in Java are *invariant*, i.e. even if class B is an A, a `Collection<B>` is *not* a `Collection<A>`.

And this is for a good reason. If your example were legal, this would be possible:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Boolean>> myHashMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Boolean>>();
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> myMap = myHashMap;
myMap.put("oops", new TreeMap<String, Boolean>());
HashMap<String, Boolean> aHashMap = myMap.get("oops"); // oops - ClassCastException!
```

Comment: But, given the declaration of myMap, what would I care what kind of Maps are put in there as long as they implement the Map interface?

Comment: @extraneon: In that case, see Boris's answer.

Comment: Java generics can have use-side variance, but not declaration-side variance. (The latter makes sense for languages where it is idiomatic for interfaces to be either "tell don't ask" or are immutable.)

Comment: I understand the why from a technical point of view, it made the implementation of generics easier. But from a functional point of view it's not all that logical. If I say (which I can't do) that my map contains map values, than I also commit to not getting a specific type of map out of there. But I can't say this map contains maps, but it must contain a specific type of map. And this is, to me, a compromise to make implementation of generics feasible, and not a feature :)

Comment: @extraneon, this specific example with maps is a bit contorted; see [this earlier answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292308/generics-method-signatures-assignments/2292339#2292339) for a simpler and (hopefully) more revealing example.

Answer (score 5):

In the second case `myMap` is a map which keys are of type `String` and values are of type `Map<String, Boolean>`. `HashMap<String, Boolean>` is not a `Map<String, Boolean>` it implements it. Therefore, this will compile:

```
Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Boolean>> myOtherMap = 
    new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Boolean>>();
```

Comment: A HashMap<String, Boolean> is a Map<String, Boolean>.

Comment: Ricky's right, the use of "is a" is unfortunate (since HashMap isa Map). Essentially using `? extends` relaxes the Generic's type requirement from exact match to inheritance hierarchy matching.

Answer (score -1):

I think that's because of the difference between `Map<String, Boolean>` and `HashMap<String,Boolean>`.
Indeed, the generics are here a specification, which must be the same on both sides. (or at least that's my opinion).