# How to create a Pojo Class for Map Under Map, For firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pojo

I got success in uploading a nexted map into firestore database like

```
 Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Boolean>>>> Fleet = new HashMap<>();
```

But I am not able to retrieve this map Task method.
I do not understand how to create an object for this kind of map.

- MainItem
      - SubItem --
            Item: Key - True/False
  This is the structure in firebase firestore database.

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636834/mapstring-mapstring-boolean-mymap-new-hashmapstring-hashmapstring-bool

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, i can give you an example. Let's take a POJO class named `users`. This class should look like this:

```
public class UserModel {
    private String userEmail, userName;
    private Boolean admin;

    public UserModel() {}

    public UserModel(String userEmail, String userName, Boolean admin) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.admin= admin;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}
    public String getUserName() {return userName;}
    public Boolean getAdmin() {return admin;}
}
```

To add a user to the database, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
UserModel userModel = new UserModel("DynamicMind@email.com", "DynamicMind", true);
rootRef.collection("users").document(userEmail).set(userModel)
```

I have also userd a `Boolean` property, to see more clearly.

Unlike in Firebase Realtime database, where we are using objects nested beneath other objects, in Cloud Firestore we use `Collections` and `Documents`. So, your database will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- users (collection)
          |
          --- DynamicMind@email.com (document)
                  |
                  --- userEmail: "DynamicMind@email.com" (property)
                  |
                  --- userName: "DynamicMind" (property)
                  |
                  --- admin: true
```

If you want to learn more about structuring a Cloud Firestore database using model classes, I recommend you see one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)**, in which I have explained step by step how to achieve this.