# private Map<List<K>, V> multiMap= new HashMap<ArrayList<K>,V>();

Tags: java, generics

What is wrong with

```
private Map<List<K>, V> multiMap= new HashMap<ArrayList<K>,V>();
```

The complier says that it `Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<ArrayList<K>,V> to Map<List<K>,V>`. Do I have to give a specific class of List? Why?

Comment: Generics is more pedantic than regular Java casts.  You cannot up cast a generic like you can with a regular expression.

Comment: Where the answers helpful? If so please accept one of them. If not, you can provide further details to help people answering the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to write

```
private Map<List<K>, V> multiMap= new HashMap<List<K>,V>();
```

The values of the generic parameters have to match exactly on both sides (as long as you don't use wildcards). The reason is that Java Generics do not have contra-/covariance (`HashMap<List>` is not a supertype of `HashMap<ArrayList>`, although `List` of course is a supertype of `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 2):

This is because a `Map<ArrayList>` is **not** a `Map<List>`, even though `ArrayList` is a `List`. Although this sounds counterintuitive, there is a good reason for this. Here is [a previous answer of mine to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292308/generics-method-signatures-assignments/2292339#2292339), which explains the reasons behind this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
private Map<? extends List<K>, V> multiMap= new HashMap<ArrayList<K>,V>();
```

Answer (score 2):

BTW: If you want a Multimap, I am pretty sure you want a `Map<K, List<V>>` and not a `Map<List<K>>, V>`. Lists make miserable Hash keys, and I can't think of any usage where it would make sense to use the List as key and a single Object as value. You should re-think your design.